# Magento - Removing the “minimum purchase” notice

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

i'm trying to remove the notice in the cart about how the customer must have a subtotal of say $20 in their cart however i still want the restriction there for when the customer tries to go into the checkout (i personally think we shouldn't remove the notice but the order comes down from up high)

at the moment, this is my code

```
$messages = $this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessages();
unset($messages[1]);
$this->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages($messages);
echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
```

i've been testing the code by going into the cart with 1 item and using the update cart button when they new qty is something stupid like 99999999999999

from the var dump i did of `$this->getMessagesBlock()`  there is a protected price of data called _messages, using `getMessages()` return an array of 2 items, one is the error about the qty at index 0, the other is an notice about the minimum purchase.

i tryed using `unset($messages[1]);` to remove the notice as a test to see if i could remove it, if it worked, i would later fix it up to search for the notice and remove it no matter where in the array it is.

i set `setMessages($messages)` and did another var dump, i can see it's been put back into `$this->getMessagesBlock()` so i thought it would work, however nothing appeared

i did a vardump of `$this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml()` and it shows an empty string

i'm wondering what i could be doing wrong here or if there is a better way to just remove the message i don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum Order Amount can be configured under System > Config > Sales > Minimum Order Amount. See the image attached [image]. Long story short, you shouldn't need to add code to the cart.phtml page in order to remove the message. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: i changed the setting and it works so to speak but i got a weird glitch, while the message is gone the notice box is still showing